# Почему не возвращает новые данные из базы данных?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Всем здрасте.
Вот код на python3, он каждые 5 сек. запрашивает таблицу и возвращает все строки, их там 27. Тоесть каждые 5 сек. возвращает одни и те же строки. Затем я добавляю в таблицу еще несколько строк, но код почему то по прежнему возвращает только старые строки, но не новые. Неважно каким образом я добавил новые данные в таблицу , они там есть 100% и закомичены тоже 100%.
Я подозреваю проблема с курсорами, я незнаю как их сбросить, и честно говоря плохо понимаю зачем они вообще нужны.

```
import pymysql
from pymysql.cursors import DictCursor

mysql_connections = None



def connection_to_mysql():

  global mysql_connections

  if mysql_connections == None or not mysql_connections.open:
  try:
  
    mysql_connections = pymysql.connect(host = db_host, user = db_username, password = db_password, db = db_dbname, charset = 'utf8mb4',    cursorclass = DictCursor)

  except pymysql.Error as err:
  
    print('Mysql error: '+str(err.args[1]))
    return False

  return True



while True:

  rows = []

  if connection_to_mysql():

    try:

      with mysql_connections.cursor() as cursor:
    
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `id` > 14 ORDER BY `id` ASC'
        cursor.execute(sql)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
    
        print(str(rows))

        cursor.close()

    except pymysql.Error as err:
  
      print('Mysql error: '+str(err.args[1]))
      break

  time.sleep(5)
```

Есть один интересный момент. Если каждые 5 сек. делать переподключение к бд то все работает как надо. Но в данном случае код один раз подключился к бд и потом уже по имеющемуся соединению с бд, каждые 5 сек запрашивает таблицу, не переподключается.
Проблема явно с курсорами, к сажалению без курсоров использовать mysql в python похоже нельзя.
Кто знает в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Посмотрите ответ на анлийском SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680684/why-do-i-need-to-reconnect-to-the-database-to-see-changes-in-table-data#29687772

Comment: хм. такая же проблема как у меня по сути. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что вы не обновляете подключение к базе данных и вы не увидите изменения в БД, пока не переподключитесь. Я советую делать таким образом:

1. Создать функцию для подключения к БД:

```
def connect():
    try:
        connection = pymysql.connect(
            host = host,
            user = user,
            password = password,
            database = db,
            cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
        )
        return connection
    except:
        sys.exit()
```

2. Перед выполнением действий в ДБ, обновлять подключение:

```
connection = connect()

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("ANY COMMAND TO EXECUTE")
        connection.commit()
```

Comment: Спасибо, но, это ведь очень низкопроизводительно